# Gregory Series not convering on the correct value

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to evaluate the gregory series for arctan, but even when I calculate 1000 terms (with the help of a computer, of course) it keeps converging on the value of x. When I consider the series for a moment, that seems to me to be the expected result.

Why is this?

Comment: For what kind of values of $x$ are you computing? If they are quite small, and you are using low precision, the machine may consider the terms  $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ and higher to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very small value of $x$, then $\hbox{arctan}(x)$ will be very close to $x$. Plug in something like $x = 1$ and if you don't start converging to $\pi/4$ after that many terms, then something is wrong with your code. You could post your code on StackOverflow and see if someone can spot the problem. There are enough people there who know a decent amount of math, so they'll know what your code is trying to do if you give a link to the Gregory series.